# I cannot see the "primary key" icon in my data file import wizard

Tags: primary-key

Ok - found a new problem - I wondered it it was just me at first - but my client - Headline Solar - whenever I import the file - it never gives me a "key" to place over the primary key column - which makes me think it has already decided to use the ExtRefId field - which is unique. Upon testing data, however, I noticed that it only imports the last record in the file of about 105 records. There is an empty "Id" field in that one record showing through Spiff. Anyone seen this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to check the case of the sheet name, which will become your table name - example - if you named the sheet "Sales" - change this to "sales" and re-import. The Primary Key icon will return.

You may need to remove the table, first, through CAMP, however. Attempt to fix before removing the table in CAMP.